# WPF - Confusion with namespaces and "odd" errors

Tags: wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces

I've been trying to get my head around XAML and it's namespaces and I just cannot seem to get the logics of things. For example, I'm trying to animate a gridrow's GridLength property following a tutorial. I can get the sample code to run just fine. But trying to actually port the features into my own code seems to be impossible. I always run into odd errors which doesn't occur in the source code. Animating the GridLength property isn't possible, so I need to create a new .vb file containing the code making it possible.

But trying to actually reach what's in there I can't get to work.

In my Window.xaml file I have this at the top:

```
xmlns:gridanim="clr-namespace:HDI_WPF_GridAnimation_vb"
```

Which targets a GridLengthAnimation.vb file. In that file you have this:

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation
Imports System.Windows

Public Class GridLengthAnimation
    Inherits AnimationTimeline
```

Back in the Window.xaml, getting contact with "GridLengthAnimation" is impossible:

```
<gridanim:GridLengthAnimation></gridanim:GridLengthAnimation>
```

I get an error message saying:

```
The name "GridLengthAnimation" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:HDI_WPF_GridAnimation_vb".
```

What is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see your nameSpace declaration around your class

```
  Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation
  Imports System.Windows
  Namespace HDI_WPF_GridAnimation_vb
   Public Class GridLengthAnimation
      Inherits AnimationTimeline
```

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't do anything. It's not in the source code either and that works just fine.

Comment: Could you please tell if this looks to be ok? I really cannot understand why this keeps happening :(

Answer (score 0):

If the HDI_WPF_GridAnimation_vb namespace is not in the same assembly as Window.xaml, you need to reference the assembly by adding it like this :


`xmlns:gridanim="clr-namespace:HDI_WPF_GridAnimation_vb;assembly=asmName"`